# Cómo puedo buscar una palabra dentro de un String por coincidencia de caracteres?

Tags: java

**Tengo que crear un programa en el que inserte una entrada de texto , cualquiera. y en el caso de tener dentro de este texto un "te odio" conseguir detectarlo y que me digo si lo contiene o no. 
Este seria el enunciado del ejercicio:**

*Miker Chiménez ve cosas escondidas en cualquier lado. Una mancha de humedad en la pared se le antoja la cara de la anterior propietaria de una casa; el sonido del viento le parece un susurro venido del más allá; una nube con forma peculiar le convence de la existencia de vida extraterrestre...
Ahora le ha dado por ver mensajes ocultos en cualquier sitio. Por poner un ejemplo, si lee el siguiente titular: "El presidente del Gobierno se somete esta noche al escrutinio de varios periodistas en Televisión Española.", se las ingenia para leer un "te odio" oculto que le mantiene en vela toda la noche:
El presidenTE del Gobierno se sOmete esta noche al escrutinio De varIos periOdistas en Televisión Española.
Crea un programa para ayudar a Miker Chiménez a automatizar la búsqueda de estos mensajes.
El programa leerá inicialmente un entero que le indicará cuántos casos de prueba vendrán a continuación. Cada uno de estos casos de prueba estará formado por dos líneas; la primera indica el titular donde buscar un mensaje oculto y la segunda indica el mensaje a buscar. Ten en cuenta que no hace falta distinguir entre mayúsculas y minúsculas y que los espacios del mensaje oculto no son relevantes, es decir, no hace falta que existan en el mensaje original, pero sí deben aparecer el resto de caracteres (signos de puntuación, comillas, etc.). 
La entrada contendrá únicamente letras del alfabeto inglés, por lo que no aparecerán vocales con tilde. Además, podrían aparecer múltiples espacios consecutivos.*

En la parte en la que estoy atascado es en la detectar el te odio en el String . El ejemplo de entrada de texto con el que estoy trabajando para detectar el "te odio" es este : 
*...dente ...somete ... de varios periodistas ..*

Y el trozo de codigo que tengo hasta ahora y donde estoy atascado es este:

```
package prog;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class p3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Texto");
        String entrada = "";
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        entrada = sc.nextLine();

        String abcd = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

        for (int i = 0; i <entrada.length (); i ++) { 
            char letra = entrada.charAt (i);

            if (letra == abcd.charAt(19)) {
                System.out.println(letra);
            } 
            if (letra == abcd.charAt(4)) {
                System.out.println(letra);
            }
            if (letra == abcd.charAt(14)) {
                System.out.println(letra);
            }
            if (letra == abcd.charAt(3)) {
                System.out.println(letra);
            }
            if (letra == abcd.charAt(8)) {
                System.out.println(letra);
            }        
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una posible solución a tu problema podría ser esta. Espero te sirva!

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    int numCasos = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine();
    int count = 0;
    int contadorBusqueda;

    if (numCasos == 0) {

    } else {

        do {

            String texto = s.nextLine();
            String buscar = s.nextLine();

            texto = texto.replaceAll(" ", "");//quitamos los espacios
            texto = texto.toLowerCase();//convertimos texto a minusculas

            buscar = buscar.replaceAll(" ", "");
            buscar = buscar.toLowerCase();
            int indexUltimoCaracter = 0; // Variable auxiliar para guardar el ultimo indice
            contadorBusqueda = 0;// contador seteado a 0
            for (int i = 0; i < buscar.length(); i++) { // Iteramos en base al texto a buscar

                for (int j = indexUltimoCaracter; j < texto.length(); j++) { // Iteramos el texto a partir del ultimo indice encontrado
                    if (buscar.charAt(i) == texto.charAt(j)) {                                                    
                        indexUltimoCaracter = j + 1; // Aqui asignamos el ultimo indice encontrado (Sumamos 1 para que comience desde el siguiente caracter)
                        contadorBusqueda++;
                        break; // Una vez encontrado el caracter rompemos el for para pasar al siguiente caracter
                    }
                }
            }

            count++;
            if (contadorBusqueda == buscar.length()) {
                System.out.println("SI");
            } else {
                System.out.println("NO");
            }
        } while (count != numCasos);

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar pattern y matcher para encontrar cualquier palabra que indiques en un array o lista:

```
String texto = "\"El presidente del Gobierno se somete esta noche al escrutinio de varios periodistas en Televisión Española.\n" +
                "se las ingenia para leer un \"te odio\" oculto que le mantiene en vela toda la noche: El presidente del Gobierno se somete esta noche al escrutinio" +
                "De varios periodistas en Televisión Española. Crea un programa para ayudar a Miker Chiménez a automatizar la búsqueda de estos mensajes." +
                "El programa leerá inicialmente un entero que le indicará cuántos casos de prueba vendrán a continuación.";

        List<String> toke = new ArrayList<>(); // Aqui creamos una List donde podemos luego indicar lo que deseemos buscar
        toke.add("te odio"); // Añadimos a la lista una palabra o frase que queramos encontrar

        String patternString = "\\b(" + StringUtils.join(toke, "|") + ")\\b"; // Declaramos la condicion de busqueda, donde busca cada parametro de la lista por todo el texto
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(texto);

        while (matcher.find()) { // Con un System.print normal o format mostramos lo que buscabamos y en que posicion para "ayudar" un poco mas al usuario
            System.out.println("Palabra encontrada en "+ matcher.start() +" - "+ (matcher.end()-1));
        }
```

En el while para ayudar te indica en que posición se encuentra. Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: El OP quiere saber si un conjunto de palabras están contenidas dentro de un texto, sin necesidad de ser consecutivas. Por ejemplo, buscar "te odio" en el texto: "tú eres un modesto ingenuo" las palabras buscadas estarían en "Tú Eres un mODesto IngenuO" --> T E OD I O.

Answer (score 0):

Usa contains para saber si la cadena contiene esa expresión

```
String entrada = "";
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
entrada = sc.nextLine();
if(entrada.contains("te odio")){
 // contiene
}else{
 // no contiene
}
```

Comment: Lo acabo de probar , el problema es que tiene que sacar "te odio" aun que no este junto , mientras el string contenga las palabras del  "te odio" . Por ejemplo Teo dijo "si". Teo-di-o , no se si me he explicado bien

Answer (score -1):

Con indexof puedes encontrar la posicion en la cadena. Si no aparece en ella devuelve -1.

```
String entradaSubstr = entrada;
boolean bValid = true;

if (entradaSubstr.indexOf("t")!=-1)
    entradaSubstr = entradaSubstr.substring(entradaSubstr.indexOf("t")+1, entradaSubstr.size());
else
    bValid = false;

if (entradaSubstr.indexOf("e")!=-1 && bValid)
    entradaSubstr = entradaSubstr.substring(entradaSubstr.indexOf("e")+1, entradaSubstr.size());
else
    bValid = false;

.....
```

O con una expresión regular:
    {[^t]*t[^e]*e     ......    }